# Autofill Conditional Format With Data Validation in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, conditional-statements, background-color

I have created a custom formula from another post that changes the color of an entire row based on drop down Data Validation of a cell: eg.

Entire row color becomes red if value "stop" in A3

Entire row color becomes orange if value "caution" in A3

Entire row color becomes green if value "go" in A3

Conditional Format applies to range - A3:N3

Format cells if... - "Custom formula is"

Custom Formula - =SEARCH("stop",$A3)

Formatting style: red fill background

(etc for orange, green)

Is there a way to autofill these conditions (red/orange/green fills based on drop down validation value) down the columns instead of manually doing this for every row?

Thanks alot

PS. I have also tried using Custom Formula: =$A3="stop" 

but again, when I fill down it screws up the line entries for rows below.

I'd rather not do this for 300 individual rows manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting range A3:N1000 or bigger and apply Conditional Format with the formula:

```
 =$A3="stop"
```

This should work for the whole range, not only 3-d column.

Comment: That works perfectly, saved me a heap of extra work - Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you, could you tick this answer as correct, please?